Relating integral $ \int f(t) g(x-t) h(y-t)dt $ of three functions to convolution
I wanted to know if the following integral can be related to a convolution:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) g(x-t) h(y-t)dt 
\end{equation}
Actually, i'm interested in the special case where the three functions are equal.
$$ f=g=h $$
Also, my functions are exponentials:
$$ f(x) = e^{j(x)} $$
So the integral can be expressed as:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{j(t)+j(x-t)+j(y-t)} dt 
\end{equation}

One way of expressing the integral as convolution follows from the definition. $f(z)g(x-z) \star h(z)$

Could you explain it? Doing a change of variables $z=y-t$ leaves the integral as:
$$ -\int f(y-z)g(x-y+z)h(z)dz $$
¿Or do you mean? Performing an extra integral?

Your integral is also correct. Convolution can be done by mirroring/shifting either variables. $f(u) \star g(u) = \int_{u=-\infty}^{\infty} f(u) g(v-u) du = \int_{u=-\infty}^{\infty} f(v-u) g(u) du$. I did the former, you did the latter. Maybe I don't understand your requirement fully.

Another relationship in the form of convolution comes from Fourier Transform. Your integral is also $F(u) \star e^{-i 2 \pi x u} G(-u) \star e^{-i 2 \pi y u} H(-u)$ at $v=0$.

Thanks! that fourier transform might be useful! My problem is, after performing the change of variables, $f$ and $g$ don't have the same variable, so i'm not sure if that's a valid expresion for a convolution. I would think i should have $f(w - z)g(w - z)$ for some variable $w$, but $f$ and $g$ have different $w$'s.

Just curious- what is your $j(x)$ definition?

It's actually a generic function. It should be even. I was using $j(x)=x^2$ for trying out things, but my goal is working with a generic $j(x)$.

Sorry I don't know how to deal with the generic case. For $j(x) = -x^2$, closed forms exist if you use the FT method. Good luck with your research

Thank you for your help!
